# A CD players plays songs until a certain artist is selected.

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose you have a CD player with 10 CDs where 9 of those CDs belong to an artist A and 1 CD belongs to an artist B.  Suppose this CD player will pick a CD at random, and from that CD it will pick a song.  It will repeat this process until it picks a song from artist B.  At which point it will turn off.
>
> Give the probability that the CD player turns off after:
>
> (a)  The sixth song.
>   (b)  At least five songs.
>   (c)  Now suppose that the CD player will run until two songs have been played by artist B.

For this problem I believe we use the geometric distribution because we want this to run until it fails.  I'm still working on developing intuition for geometric vs binomial vs negative binomial.

(a) $\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^5$
(b)  $P(\text{At least five songs A})=1-P(\text{At most five songs by artist A})=1-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{5}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{n-1}.$
(c)  $\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2$

Comment: (c) looks in conflict with *"It will repeat this process until it picks a song from artist B. At which point it will turn off."*

Comment: (a) looks correct. (b) looks wrong and I would have thought was easier than (a)

Comment: Right, (c) is like a new situation.

Comment: Also, I noticed I left off an index on (b).

Comment: The song that it picks from the chosen CD is totally irrelevant. So you can remove all mention of songs from the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is correct.

b) $$1-\sum_{n=1}^4P(\text{off after the }n\text{-th song})=1-\sum_{n=1}^4 \frac1{10}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{n-1}$$

ci) There will be turned off after the $6$-th song if this song is from B and exactly one of the preceding $5$ songs is from B. These events have probabilities: $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\binom51\frac1{10}\left(\frac9{10}\right)^4$ respectively, and are independent. So we end up with a probability:$$\binom51\left(\frac1{10}\right)^2\left(\frac9{10}\right)^4$$

cii) There will be turned off after at least $5$ songs if among the first $4$ there is at most $1$ song from B. Can you handle it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure I following cii.  I thought that would be taken care of in ci.

Comment: I made a mistake in cii and repaired (sorry). In ci the case is handled that the $6$-th song *is* the second song of B (so a turn off follows). In cii the case is handled that the second song of B will not be recorded among the first $4$ (originally I wrote $5$) so that there is a turn off after at least $5$ songs.